# C#: Sanitize XML text values with XmlTextWriter?

Tags: c#, xml, escaping, sanitization, xmltextwriter

I'm using `XmlTextWriter` to serialize and persist some of my data. Several of the fields I serialize are based on user input (e.g. Username). Today I use the `WriteElementString` method of `XmlTextWriter`.

My question is: the second parameter of `WriteElementString` is the text value to be written. How can I sanitize it prior to writing?

An example code:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("filename.xml", null);

writer.WriteStartElement("User");
writer.WriteElementString("Username", inputUserName);
writer.WriteElementString("Email", inputEmail);
writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.Close();
```

The variables `inputUserName` and `inputEmail` are user-input, and I would like to sanitize/escape them prior to writing.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly do you need to escape there? `WriteElementString` will do all escaping needed by XML already (i.e. `&` -> `&amp;`, `<` -> `&lt;`, etc)

Comment: So WriteElementString is completely safe? (it makes sense when you say it, I just didn't know it was the case)

Comment: It is "safe" in a sense that it guarantees that output will be valid XML, and that when you read it back, you'll get the same string.

Answer (score -2):

You could safe these Values as [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp) that will be safest you can do with xml.

Prior you should check the values via `RegEx` or any other validation.

Comment: Why the downvote? CDATA is safest way to hold you XML valid an contain everyting inside you wish?

Comment: CDATA does not matter at all. It's just a way to write text without needing to escape it. The code used by the OP will escape everything properly.

Comment: Written as CDATA it will not be escaped, but working properly.